# how to read data from database created by asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the database from my asp.net mvc (Identity 2.0), and it has values:

[image]

In account controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
   (...)
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
   (...)
}
```

and

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
 (...)
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
 (...)
}
```

but now I have created a console application and have connect to my database, but how can I read off this values?

for example: for admin i have password: admin123, but here's two values for this:
`passwordHash` and `SecurityStamp` (?)

Answer (score 0):

You have used `UserManager` to create the user, do the same for [`FindAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497545%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) or [`FindByNameAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497543%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't reimplement these features, but rather use the classes provided by the framework.
For instance, you could use the `PasswordHasher` class to verify a password with the `VerifyPassword` method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordhasher.verifyhashedpassword(v=vs.111).aspx).

Also, you can look around the source code of the classes in the Identity namespace, such as `PasswordHasher` and `UserManager`. Unfortunately, the Identity namespace is not open source at the moment (https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Readme.markdown), but they shouldn't be too complex to understand with Reflector or JustDecompile.

Comment: Ok, well if i have a page with database and create local application, then How can I get the trustly data? (on local app):/

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You can connect to the same database from a Console app as well and query the same data that your web app uses.

Comment: Yes, but data is encoded and i'm searching a way to encode it to normal values.

Comment: You mean you'd like to get the password back in plain text? You cannot do that, that is the whole point of hashing the password and storing only the hash, so that a possible attacker would not be able to get the passwords in plain text.